# DataAnnotations Required within a non required object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-annotations

I am trying to create an object with Data Annotations and use other objects inside it which use Data Annotations themselves.
Ex:

```
public class ParticipationModel
{

    [Required]
    public Object1 obj { get; set; }

    public List<Object2> Listofobj2 { get; set; }

}

public class Object2
{
    [Required]
    public String TypeOfThing { get; set; }
}
```

My Question is if the Data Annotation will only require the TypeOfThing if the Listofobj2 is in fact instantiated.

While  testing had a couple of weird reactions from this Type of Data Structure.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1737269.aspx). Server-side validation should work, client side won't. That is assuming we are talking about asp.net mvc here

Comment: Its a rest service but i dont think thats it :/